# write to /etc/host from cron each for n minutes of each hour

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, cron

i need help with bash script and cron. The simple idea is to lock some website domain name for n minutes of each hour, (45 minutes of each hour but randomly lock youtube.com or facebook). I do not know how the bash script should be and which cron rule need to use and how to run it with root rights ?

*/45 * * * * for cron rule but how to make it run randomly (0-45 or from 10-55 ...) And how should look like bash script (which lock the domain name or write to host file)?

Comment: Browsers are going to cache DNS locally, so this may not work as you expect it to …

Comment: i am trying to create bash script which will be run by cron, but it not so easy as i thinking

Comment: "cache DNS locally" dnsmasq: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dnsmasq

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely do this by editing the host file.

this could be more complicated but here's how I think of solving this problem:

2 bash scripts (one to add a block and another to remove the block)
create an extra hosts file (with the domain block entries)
the bash scripts will just swap the hosts files
two cron jobs that run at the proper times to run your bash scripts that either enable or disable the block
(cron jobs as root of course since they're changing the hosts file)